# how to set Tamil text in android widget?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have brought the tamil font in to list view. I have unicodes for tamil fonts and I am setting that to typeface of textview.. so the font gets displayed well. The problem now is i need a widget to display the same dynamically. as the widgets dnt have a typeface to support the font is not getting displayed instead the unicodes are displayed . Can any one find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

create a Style and apply it to the widget you want to use.
see here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: that Tamil font i stored in assets folder. so if add "<item name="android:typeface">tsckomathi</item>" it's shows error